# What is the "standard method" for administrate this Wordpress layout?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was thinking about creating a Wordpress theme that has a layout similar to this: http://themeforest.net/item/salient-responsive-multipurpose-theme/full_screen_preview/4363266. This is quite a common layout for many websites and I wonder how I should handle all the fields from the administrations panel.

For example, in the first white block on this page there are four elements. What is each element here? A page or a widget or some custom admin settings for this theme? Which is the best way to handle the administration of all those custom fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On that particular page, each of those four elements is a div. These are probably set in a Theme Options section of the dashboard.

However, a widgetised area with four text widgets would be far easier to set up, and almost as easy to manage in the backend for the site user.